# Trying to get TRACE level logging from Geckodriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, geckodriver

I'm trying to get trace logging information out of the gecko driver, in order to debug some issues we're having with moving to newer versions of Python, Robot Framework, Selenium, Firefox.

See in the DEBUG robot output below, I'm setting the capabilities to include log level arguments as part of moz:firefoxOptions.

When the capabilities are printed out for Open Browser, the moz:firefoxOptions value has been replaced with the profile info, so I never get tracing set.

```
20190219 13:07:22.461 - INFO - {'browserName': 'firefox', 'marionette': True, 'acceptInsecureCerts': True, 'moz:firefoxOptions': {'prefs': {'log': {'level': 'trace'}}, 'args': ['-headless', '-profile', '/tmp/tmpimda__f2']}, 'binary': '/usr/bin/firefox'}

20190219 13:07:22.461 - INFO - +--- END KW: BuiltIn.Log (1)

20190219 13:07:22.461 - INFO - +--- START KW: CustomLib.AdminClass.Open Browser [ ${LOGIN URL} | ${BROWSER} | desired_capabilities=${dc} | ff_profile_dir=${profile} ]

20190219 13:07:22.462 - INFO - Opening browser 'Firefox' to base url 'https://HOST:PORT/bmmadmin/login.jsp'.

20190219 13:07:22.480 - DEBUG - POST http://127.0.0.1:38132/session {"capabilities": {"firstMatch": [{}], "alwaysMatch": {"browserName": "firefox", "acceptInsecureCerts": true, "moz:firefoxOptions": {"profile": "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"}}}, "desiredCapabilities": {"browserName": "firefox", "acceptInsecureCerts": true, "moz:firefoxOptions": {"profile": "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"}, "binary": "/usr/bin/firefox", "marionette": true}}
```

Anyone have any ideas what I may be doing wrong here?  And/OR some alternative methods of getting trace logging from geckodriver?

BTW:  the moz:firefoxOptions I'm setting may not be correct, they're just the latest combination I have tried, but I can't tell what is going to work until the options I set are actually being sent to firefox.

```
Environment:

Python 3.6.3    
geckodriver 0.24.0 ( 2019-01-28)    
Mozilla Firefox 60.4.0

PIP:

requests (2.21.0)    
robotframework (3.1.1)    
robotframework-requests (0.5.0)    
robotframework-selenium2library (3.0.0)    
robotframework-seleniumlibrary (3.3.1)    
selenium (3.141.0)    
setuptools (40.8.0)    
urllib3 (1.24.1)


ROBOT:

Open Browser To Login Page
    ${dc}=    CustomLib.Get Desired Capabilities    ${BROWSER}    
    Set To Dictionary   ${dc}   
    ...                 binary                         ${PATH TO MARIONETTE}
    Log    ${dc}    
    ${profile}=    CustomLib.Create FF Profile
    Open Browser    ${LOGIN URL}    ${BROWSER}    desired_capabilities=${dc}    ff_profile_dir=${profile}


PYTHON:

@keyword
def get_desired_capabilities(browser):
        _capabilities = {'ff' : DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX,
                    'firefox' : DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
                    } 

        browserKey = str(browser).lower()
        desired = _capabilities[browserKey]
        BuiltIn().log("get_desired_capabilities B4 :" + str(desired))
        #THIS IS ASSUMING FIREFOX
        desired['marionette'] = True
        desired['acceptSslCerts'] = True
        desired['ignoreProtectedModeSettings'] = True
        desired['headless'] = True
        desired['moz:webdriverClick'] = True
        desired['moz:firefoxOptions'] = {'log':{'level':'trace'}, 'args':['-headless']}
        #desired['moz:firefoxOptions']['log'] = {'level':'trace'}
        #desired['moz:firefoxOptions']['args'] = ['-headless']
        BuiltIn().log("get_desired_capabilities returning :" + str(desired))
        return desired

@keyword
def create_ff_download_profile(path):
        from selenium import webdriver
        BuiltIn().log('PATH: ' + path)
        fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
        fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False);
        fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", 'text/xml,text/plain,application/octet-stream')
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", path)      
        fp.update_preferences()     
        return fp.path
```

thanks,
Tom

Comment: I am getting some output using MOZ_LOG - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Gecko_Logging

Answer (score 3):

This is how I set the log level to be trace in Firefox:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Keywords ***
    ${options}=    Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver.firefox.options'].Options()    sys
    ${options.log.level}=    Set Variable    trace
    ${driver}=    Create Webdriver    Firefox    options=${options}
    Go To    https://www.google.com
```

It's basically following this python pattern from the [firefox docs](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/TraceLogs.html#python) and translating it into Robotframework

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you.  I would like to use that, but the driver is never created explicitly in our tests/libraries.  (We do some things with the FirefoxProfile).  We are calling Open Browser with the capabilities specified, and far as I know, that's the only way I can pass Firefox options.  But the moz:firefoxOptions seems to get overwritten.

Comment: @TRC Sorry that won't fit your needs. Can you add the code you use to invoke the browser instance. Maybe I or someone else can suggest a solution based on that

Comment: @cullzie Thanks, I should have done that to start with :)

Comment: Ok you should be able to switch to Create Webdriver based on what you describe. You just need the additional step of opening the required URL in Create Webdriver. Just update this line: `${driver}=    Create Webdriver    Firefox    desired_capabilities=${dc}    firefox_profile=${profile}    options=${options}` and in your `def create_ff_download_profile(path):` method just return the profile object instead of just the path: `return fp`. If you can test this I will update the answer if it works.